# Rails routes and limiting authentication by association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a group of scoped resources.

```
scope '/:org_name', :as => 'organization' do
  resources :users
end
```

An organization has many users.

What I'd like is for my routes to look like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/<organization-name>/users/1
```

This currently works fine.

The problem is that I can change the 'organization-name' part to anything I'd like, and it does not affect anything. If I put any string in there, I am still authenticated as that user.

what am I missing?

Comment: Until you actually do something with `params[:org_name]` in your controller/actions you cannot expect changing that part of the URL to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Deefour mentioned you will need to do this manually. The problem you're explaining here is authorization not authentication, take a look at a gem like [CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)

To explain it with an example. You would have to ensure the user is a member of the given organization. This could look something like this(given you have an current_user which represents the logged in user):

Controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_organization, :ensure_organization_membership, :only => :show

  def show
    @user = @organization.users.find(params[:id])
  end

  def find_organization
    @organization = Organization.find_by_name(params[:org_name])
  end

  def ensure_organization_membership
    # Make sure the current_user(Logged in user) is a member of the company before showing the user profile
    @organization.include(:users).member_of?(current_user)
  end
end
```

And in the model

```
class Organization
....
  def member_of?(user)
    users.includes?(user)
  end
...
end
```

Hope that helps.